# What is the updated version of assign_variable?

Tags: variable, ee5

In former days **{assign_variable: my_var="foo"}** was a very handy tool. I haven't used it for some time and discovered that it was deprecated in EE 4.x but was not able to determine what if anything it has been replaced with. Is there a "modern" equivalent? If so, would you mind sharing?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean assigning variables to an embed template?

Comment: Yes. You create the variable at the top of the template and then you can use the variable values in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally tripped over the answer while looking for something else. The feature actually still exists but it is called:

```
{preload_replace:my_category="britain"}
```

You can find out more about it here: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/preload-replacement.html#preload-text-replacements

Answer (score 1):

The best way of creating transient values within a template is through EE's built in [layout variable](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/layouts.html#layout-variables) system.

Layout variables can be defined as single values or as part of an addressable array, and can contain anything you can generate as tag output within a template.

The only wrinkle is that the variables only get instantiated when EE template processing transfers to a subsequent template (using EE's [Template Layout](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/layouts.html) system).  So the most minimal way of defining and then using a variable would be something like this:

**First Template in chain**

```
{layout='template_2'}
{layout:set name="my_var" value="foo"}
{layout:set name="my_var_another_option"}foo{/layout:set}
```

**Second Template in chain** ('template_2')

```
<h1>Here is the content of my_var {layout:my_var}</h1>
<p>And here is the content of my_var_another_option {layout:my_var_another_option}.</p>
```

I'll leave you to read about the layout variable array option in the docs... :)

HTH

Comment: Obviously not as simple as in times past. Thank you for your feedback.